# Collect ID and number of rows from SQL query in column value

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
           ID      SQL          
0     ID_24     Select * from table1
1     ID_42     Select * from table2
```

I want to create a for loop that iterates over these rows, and adds the number of rows from executing each query next to the ID.

Desired output:

```
ID_24   7
ID_42   12
```

I tried to split this up in two parts, by printing out the SQL query like this:

```
def sql_collect(df):
    for row in df.itertuples():
        row = print(row.SQL)
```

But now I  want the individual SQL statements to execute and count the number of rows that it returns.

Would greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right, you want a SELECT that will count you number of rows in it?

You can just use this on each table and than make update query:

```
SELECT count(*) from table1
```

Comment: I would like to have a For-loop that iterates over the rows, and gives as result the ID and the number of rows after executing the query. For that, I think the loop should contain some SQL execution part, but I am not sure how.